# Save data as key value pair in windows 8 metro style app?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

In my application I want to save the data as key value pair. How is this possible?

Comment: What kind of data?  What do you need to do with the data once it is stored?  Where does it need to be "saved"?  What language are you using?

Comment: I'd be happy to answer this question, but as James pointed out, I need MUCH more information to actually help you.